# Агрегатная функция Count() в запросе с несколькими таблицами

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

Есть две таблицы.

Первая таблица `Reader` содержит сведения о читателях библиотеки. 
Поля таблицы: `LibraryCardNumber, ReaderSurname, ReaderName, ReaderPatronymic, BirthDate, Address, Phone`.

Вторая таблицы `BookDelivery` содержит информацию о выданних книгах.
Поля таблицы: `BookID, ReaderLibraryCardNumber, DateStart, DateReturned`.

Мне нужно вывести информацию о читателях и количестве виданных им книг.

С помощью агрегатной функции Count() я находила количество таким образом:

```
SELECT  ReaderLibraryCardNumber as [Номер читательского билета], 
        Count(*) as [Количество книг]
FROM BookDelivery 
GROUP BY ReaderLibraryCardNumber;
```

Но мне недостаточно знать только номер читательского билета, нужна и другая информация о читателе из таблицы Reader (например, имя и фамилия читателя). Пыталась получить её таким образом:

```
SELECT BookDelivery.ReaderLibraryCardNumber as [Номер читательского билета], 
       Reader.ReaderName as [Имя], 
       Reader.ReaderSurname as [Фамилия], 
       Count(*) as [Количество книг]
FROM BookDelivery, Reader
WHERE BookDelivery.ReaderLibraryCardNumber = Reader.LibraryCardNumber
GROUP BY ReaderLibraryCardNumber;
```

Но Access ругается: "Ваш запрос не содержит указанное выражение "Имя" как часть агрегатной функции". Можно ли как-то оформить запрос, чтобы и количество вычислялось, и поля из другой таблицы выводилися?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Reader.LibraryCardNumber as [Номер читательского билета], 
       Reader.ReaderName as [Имя], 
       Reader.ReaderSurname as [Фамилия], 
       Count(*) as [Количество книг]
FROM BookDelivery, Reader
WHERE BookDelivery.ReaderLibraryCardNumber = Reader.LibraryCardNumber
GROUP BY Reader.LibraryCardNumber, 
         Reader.ReaderName, 
         Reader.ReaderSurname;
```